# Unresponsive data.getData for PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uri

One of the Activities on an app i am building is a profile update activity with an option to upload display picture. I am trying to implement upload picture option using Picasso through the following code. So far i am unable to retrieve the picture from the phone with a constant null for Uri and failure to display picture in the ImageView due to that.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;



public class UploadProfilePicture extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageView imageViewUploadPic;
private FirebaseAuth authProfile;
private StorageReference storageReference;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST =1 ;
private Uri uriImage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_profile_pciture);

    getActionBar();

    authProfile = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = authProfile.getCurrentUser();


    Button buttonUploadPictureChoose = findViewById(R.id.upload_profile_pic_choose_button);
    Button buttonUploadProfilePicture = findViewById(R.id.upload_profile_pic_upload_button);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imageViewUploadPic = findViewById(R.id.imageView_profile_pic_upload);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getReference("UsersDisplayPictures");

    Uri uri = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl();

    //Set User's current DP in ImageView (if uploaded already). Will be using Picasso
    //Regular URIs
    Picasso.with(UploadProfilePicture.this).load(uri).into(imageViewUploadPic);

    //choosing image from phone to upload
    buttonUploadPictureChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFileChooser();
        }
    });
    //upload image to app
    buttonUploadProfilePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UploadPic ();
        }
    });


}

private void openFileChooser(){
    Intent intent =  new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,@Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
        uriImage = data.getData();
        imageViewUploadPic.setImageURI(uriImage);
        Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicture.this, "Picture was chosen, please click the upload button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (uriImage == null){
        Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicture.this, "Uri is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private void UploadPic(){
    if (uriImage != null){

        // save the image with uid of the currently logged user
        StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(authProfile.getCurrentUser().getUid() + " . " + getFileExtension(uriImage));

        //Upload image to storage
        fileReference.putFile(uriImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUri = uri;
                        firebaseUser = authProfile.getCurrentUser();

                        //Finally set the display image of the user after upload
                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setPhotoUri(downloadUri).build();
                        firebaseUser.updateProfile(profileUpdates);

                    }
                });

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicture.this, "Picture Upload is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UploadProfilePicture.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicture.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicture.this, "Something went wrong!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(UploadProfilePicture.this, "No file was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

//Obtaining File Extension of the image
private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver CR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(CR.getType(uri));
}
```

No errors or noticeable Logcat line related. Simply it would exit the Picture picker and would not display the image in the imageView. Of course it would Toast the message of " Uri is null" since it is following the if statement included to follow the process steps to see the missing task !

Is my code of choosing and uploading picture is wrong or something is missing >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a syntax error in the if statement within the onActivityResult

it was:

```
 if (resultCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
```

Correction :

```
 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
```

At the moment the issue is resolved and image could be chosen and displayed within the app.

Facing a new issue with this code but this should be for another question if needed

```
 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
User does not have permission to access this object.
 Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
```